# How to get a Json response from alfresco

Tags: rest, alfresco

I'm trying to get an alfresco json response but so far i'm getting this kind of response

for an endpoint as such :

**https://exaple.com/alfresco/webdav/Directory1/subDirectory1/**

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta content="HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 26 sept. 2004), see www.w3.org" name="generator"/>
      <title>Alfresco Content Repository</title>
      <style type="text/css">body { font-family: Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 12pt; background-color: white; }
table { font-family: Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 12pt; background-color: white; }
.listingTable { border: solid black 1px; }
.textCommand { font-family: verdana; font-size: 10pt; }
.textLocation { font-family: verdana; font-size: 11pt; font-weight: bold; color: #2a568f; }
.textData { font-family: verdana; font-size: 10pt; }
.tableHeading { font-family: verdana; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; color: white; background-color: #2a568f; }
.rowOdd { background-color: #eeeeee; }
.rowEven { background-color: #dddddd; }</style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2">
         <tr>
            <td class="textLocation" colspan="4">Directory listing for /Directory1/subDirectory1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="4" height="10"/>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="listingTable" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2">
         <tr>
            <td width="*" class="tableHeading">Name</td>
            <td width="10%" class="tableHeading">Size</td>
            <td width="20%" class="tableHeading">Type</td>
            <td width="25%" class="tableHeading">Modified Date</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="rowOdd">
            <td class="textData" colspan="4">
               <a href="/alfresco/webdav/Directory1">[Up a level]</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="rowEven">
            <td class="textData">
               <a href="/alfresco/webdav/Directory1/subDirectory1/File.ini">File.ini</a>
            </td>
            <td class="textData">21.7 Kb</td>
            <td class="textData">Plain Text</td>
            <td class="textData">Thu, 09 Jan 2020 11:51:45 GMT</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="rowOdd">
            <td class="textData">
               <a href="/alfresco/webdav/Directory1/subDirectory1/File2.OLB">File2.OLB</a>
            </td>
            <td class="textData">502.2 Kb</td>
            <td class="textData">application/x-tika-msoffice</td>
            <td class="textData">Tue, 09 Nov 2021 08:00:35 GMT</td>
         </tr>

      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

How could i get a json response other a html one .

I'n forms i'm reading about cmis but couldn't find a response

When i use CMIS , with this endpoint

**https://exaple.com/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom**

I'm getting this response :

```html
<html>
<h1>Axis HTTP Servlet</h1>
Hi, you have reached the AXIS HTTP Servlet. Normally you would be hitting this URL with a SOAP client rather than a
browser.
<p>In case you are interested, my AXIS transport name appears to be '<b>http</b>'

</html>
```

Note , i didn't specified a folder

I'm new to **alfresco**

Comment: Call a CMIS or Public API endpoint rather than a WebDav endpoint?

Comment: how could i do that

Comment: @Gagravarr I edited my post with calling a CMIS endpoint . I'm getting a 200OK status but  the response is not good ! I'm missing something

Comment: You haven't told us what you're trying to do with Alfresco, so it is hard to tell you what API to hit....

Comment: @Gagravarr I'm trying to get the files under https://exaple.com/alfresco/webdav/Directory1/subDirectory1/

Comment: im able to get a 200ok response with hitting this endpoint https://exaple.com/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom but not able to get a result of files

Comment: You probably just want https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#/nodes/listNodeChildren - see also https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/5.2/develop/rest-api-guide/ for general info on the APIs

Comment: @Gagravarr to get files under a folder , my endpoint would be https://exaple.com//alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/  ??

Comment: I really don't get why im always having a 200ok response with no results with result as such : :    Hi, you have reached the AXIS HTTP Servlet. Normally you would be hitting this URL with a SOAP client rather than a
browser.
<p>In case you are interested, my AXIS transport name appears to be '<b>http</b>'

Comment: @Gagravarr still blocked any suggestions please ?

Comment: Nope, the public APIs work just fine for me, don't know what you've managed to stuff up in your installation or config...